# Ayuda con Data Source OLEDB

Tags: string, ms-access, oledb

Hola muy buenos días colegas estoy tratando de crear una cadena de conexión por medio de un programa el problema que tengo es que cuando voy a agregar la cadena y le digo a la aplicación que conecte me da el siguiente error.

No es un nombre de archivo valido.

La cadena que estoy utilizando es esta.

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|muestra.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=datos2017
```

Si utilizo la siguiente cadena de conexion me dice que debo de tener el archivo o la DB en C:\

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\muestra.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=datos2017
```

Y si uso esta cadena me dice que tengo que tener el archivo de conexion en C:\Windows\System32\

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=muestra.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=datos2017
```

Como puedo hacer para que esta cadena de conexión sepa que el archivo muestra se encuentra en la carpeta de instalación y no en otro lugar? ya utilice también MapPacht y nada si alguien puede orientarme o ayudarme de algún modo yo se los agradeceria

Por cierto lo que estoy haciendo está construido en logtion radbuilder, que es como una especie de constructor rápido de aplicaciones básicas.

Saludos y Gracias.

Comment: Tal vez esto te dé una pista: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13169526/using-a-relative-path-in-connection-string-for-access-db-in-c-sharp

Comment: ¿Puedes [edit] la pregunta agregando el código fuente *(no todo, solo lo mas relevante)* que uses para crear la cadena de conexión? además, ¿qué es `MapPacht `?

Comment: Eso es esto ve

https://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/kb/using-server-mappath-database-connection.html

El problema es que igual me tira error porque el programa no permite mucha manipulación